# How to slow down all SQL Queries?

Tags: sql-server

For testing purposes, is there a way to slow down all SQL queries?  There are ways to slow down specific queries but is there a way to slow down ALL queries?

Ideally it would be nice to have a simple way to say, all queries by [N] milliseconds.

Sloppier ways might include...
- Lower SQL Server's available memory
- Loop through other SQL statements to have an artificial load
- Create/run a seperate CPU/IO/Memory heavy process on the SQL server

However... these seem very rough and not very elegant all.  Is there something more exacting?

Comment: Presumably you're testing for this because you expect your software to keep running robustly even in the face of an overloaded or unreliable connection, so I don't see what's really "sloppy" about reducing SQL Server's resources -- it seems a better match for the test than "exact" slowdowns. If you really wanted something "exacting", it would be much better to augment the DB layer of whatever software is under test to inject the delay itself before processing the results. If that's not possible, a generic TCP proxy that delays connections or packets for port 1433 might be another option.

Comment: Re: restricting resource on SQL Server, you can use Resource Governor to set up "artificial" restrictions for clients without tampering with the server itself. This will still not give you reliable *slowdowns*, but it's at least more reproducible.

Comment: depress the `turbo` button to make your `66mhz` machine run at `33mhz`.  We're talking `SQL 6.5` on `NT` right? :)  Honestly, there is various throttling software to burn CPU cycles, disk and such, sort of lame solution but that might be what you are stuck with.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a tool which was created for this purpose, aptly name, SQL Query Stress. It's available on Github.

> Github link:  https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlQueryStress

I've been introduced to it by Brent Ozar and company. Please see the link to the article in which he introduces it and shows some of its use.

> https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-fake-load-tests-with-sqlquerystress/

Comment: This may be the only type of option.  I was hopeful that there was a way to inject a "slowness" in all queries without actually having to put a real load on the server.  That is still worthwhile but difficult for simple testing.  This type of answer will most likely be the best we can do.